# IR led extremely slow to turn completely off?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal-processing, infrared, troubleshooting, teensy

I'm working on a project where I'm simply reading the amount of light emitting from an [IR led](https://www.osram.com/ecat/Radial%20T1%203-4%20SFH%204556P/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/global/prd_pim_device_2219780/) with an [IR sensor](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/osram-opto-semiconductors-inc/BPW34FA/475-1072-ND/607276).

For some reason, after the IR led reaches full luminosity, it takes a minimum, whopping 500ms for the IR sensor's readings to drop from 65536 (16 bit resolution) to ~0.

---

**This is my circuit**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqoiDN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn by @Transistor (for verification).*

**This is my code**:

```
#include <ADC.h>

ADC* adc;

int ir_led = A8;
int ir_sensor = A9;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    configureADC();
    pinMode(ir_led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ir_sensor, INPUT);

    delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(ir_led, HIGH);
    delay(10);  // wait for ir led to reach full luminosity

    int start_time = millis();
    digitalWrite(ir_led, LOW);
    while (adc->analogRead(ir_sensor) > 50); // wait for LED to turn completely off: a reading of 50 out of 65536 is equivalent to 0 with environmental noise
    int end_time = millis();
    Serial.print("DELAY TIME (ms): ");
    Serial.println(end_time - start_time);

}


void configureADC() {
    adc = new ADC();

    adc->setAveraging(16); // set number of averages
    adc->setResolution(16); // set bits of resolution
    adc->setConversionSpeed(ADC_CONVERSION_SPEED::HIGH_SPEED_16BITS);
    adc->setSamplingSpeed(ADC_SAMPLING_SPEED::MED_SPEED);

    adc->setAveraging(16, ADC_1); // set number of averages
    adc->setResolution(16, ADC_1); // set bits of resolution
    adc->setConversionSpeed(ADC_CONVERSION_SPEED::HIGH_SPEED_16BITS, ADC_1); // change the conversion speed
    adc->setSamplingSpeed(ADC_SAMPLING_SPEED::MED_SPEED, ADC_1); // change the sampling speed

}
```

**Serial output**:

[image]

## Plotting the sensors readings:

[image]

Some delay is expected, but 500ms does not make sense. **Can someone help me figure out where this delay is coming from and why?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109043/discussion-on-question-by-ietpt123-ir-led-extremely-slow-to-turn-completely-off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is for your Opamp.
As I see, your RC value is 100nF and 1MOhms is 0.1 seconds, and your plot is a nice 1/0.1s+1 plot.
So everything is OK based on your circuit. if you want to increase speed, lower C or R to get a better speed.
Your 500 ms delay is  a 5 time of time constant of this circuit, which is also shows me that it's a first order transfer function. your exact equation in time based system is 1 - e^(-t/RC) where R and C is your capacitor and resistor in your Opamp.

Comment: Since I obviously would want to fastest possible response time, is there a minimum or optimal capacitor and resistor value that I should choose?

Comment: @letpt123 In that case, remove capacitor, or simply reduce Resistor to 1K for .1ms response time as a low value for this.

Comment: Is there any incentive for me to keep the capacitor? Why not go lower to 1 ohm or just remove the resistor as well for the fastest theoretical response time?

Comment: Your diode needs to be biased, so you need resistor and must use of a rather big one, so you can only play with capacitor, to make the circuit without delay, you can remove C but can't reduce R lower than 10K i think, where current through sensor is increased and cause sensor burning

Comment: Okay good to know, Thank you for your help